# Productos con distinto stock

Tags: php, mysql, sql

junto con saludar, les comento que estoy diseñando un pequeño sistema ecommerce (sabiendo que en el mercado existe, prestashop, opencart, etc..) solo estoy haciendo algo a medida para mi propio local.

Hoy cuanto me tocó crear la base de datos me quedo dando vuelta mucho un tema, que no pude solucionar. 
Si tengo el producto Jeans que tiene 3 variaciones de tamaño (S, L y M) y dentro de esas 3 variaciones hay 2 distintos colores (Rojo, Azul).
Cómo puedo hacer para tener un stock separado y poder controlarlo?
Por ejemplo, tengo 5 Jeans Rojos talla S y 2 Jeans Rojos talla L, 6 Jeans Azules talla S, etc..

Alguna idea de cómo modelar la base de datos ?

Estoy trabajando por procedimientos en PHP y MySQLi.

Comment: Por que tratarlos como elementos diferentes no lo ves una buena opcion, no?

Comment: @AgusBellas Hola, no puedo tratarlos como elementos diferentes ya que serían muchos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un diseño posible sería este:

Por separado las tablas `producto`, `color`,  `talla`:

### `producto`

```
ID       producto
----------------------
1        Jeans
2        Camisa
3        Zapato
```

### `color`

```
ID       color
----------------------
1        rojo
2        azul
3        blanco
```

### `talla`

```
ID       talla
----------------------
1         S
2         M
3         L
```

Y una tabla para las relaciones:

### `stock`

```
ID      id_producto    id_color     id_talla    cantidad
1            1             1            1           5         -- 5 jeans rojos talla s
2            3             2            2           7         -- 7 zapatos blancos talla M
3            2            NULL          3           1         -- 1 camisa sin color talla L
```

Es un diseño totalmente flexible. Imaginemos que hay que incorporar una tabla `marca` por ejemplo.

Imaginemos solicitudes como estas:

- ¿Cuántos productos hay de color rojo de la talla M?
- ¿Cuántos productos sin color hay?
- ¿De qué productos no tenemos en amarillo?

Quizá el modelo se pueda ampliar o modificar, todo depende. Por ejemplo, ¿hay productos con otras características como dimensiones, etc?

Las relaciones, índices y restricciones las dejo a tu cuidado.

Comment: Hola, Muchas gracias por comentar. Me parece una buena idea relacionar de esta manera, pero quizás no todos los productos tengan color y talla, quizás en algunos, solo deba elegir color y en otros solo talla, no todos los productos del ecommerce cuenta con talla y color, me entiendes? Cómo podrías relacionar de manera general, el color, la talla o el sabor por ejemplo si es necesario...

Comment: @MaikelYordan te entiendo. En esos casos, dejas `NULL` la columna en `stock`. Ahora te actualizo con un ejemplo.